# Angular routing failing for more segment when manually navigated or browser refreshes

Tags: angular, routes

I have an Angular routing issue, specifically with routing. Routing is failing more one segment when manually navigated or when the browser refreshes

```
      {path:'post',component: PostComponent}
      {path:'post/details',component: DetailsComponent}
```

when  the browser refreshes or manually navigated the first path work but the the path with /details fails with errors as shown below

```
   post:41 GET http://localhost:4200/post/runtime.js 
   post:41 GET http://localhost:4200/post/polyfills.js 
   post:41 GET http://localhost:4200/post/styles.js 
   post:41 GET http://localhost:4200/post/vendor.js 
   post:41 GET http://localhost:4200/post/main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'post'}
{ path: 'post', component: PostComponent, children: [
    { path:'details',component: DetailsComponent}
  ]
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
```

Comment: It is 100% write code. You can have some other problems see it in Module or from where are you routing or everywhere in application. but not in this code. You should write full code.